# How to write a code to display output value in every 60 minutes using panda python using csv file

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, lstm

I have temperature in a csv file. My file is updated with time . I have loaded this data to a pandas DataFrame. What I want to do is predict temperature value in next 60 minutes.

I changed the start time into 0 minutes.

After changed the start time into 0 minutes then I write the code for to display time in every 60 minutes.

```
date                  time   temp   humidity  wind                     
2018-10-03 06:00:00    0.0    63       0        0
2018-10-03 07:00:00   60.0    63       0        2
2018-10-03 08:00:00   120.0   104      11       0
2018-10-03 09:00:00   180.0   93       0        50
2018-10-03 10:00:00   240.0   177      0        2
2018-10-03 11:00:00   300.0   133      0        0
2018-10-03 12:00:00   360.0   70       0        0
2018-10-03 13:45:00   465.0   83       0        60
2018-10-03 15:00:00  540.0    127      0        50
2018-10-03 16:00:00  600.0    205      0        0
2018-10-03 17:00:00  660.0    298      0        0
2018-10-03 18:00:00  720.0    234      0        0
2018-10-03 19:00:00  780.0    148      0        20
2018-10-03 20:00:00  840.0    135      0        0
2018-10-03 21:30:00  930.0    100      0        50
2018-10-04 06:00:00    0.0    166      0        0
2018-10-04 07:00:00   60.0     0       0        0
```

After that I wrote the code for next output temperature value. mean my first output is 63 (temp) at 60 minutes.

```
time(t)        temp     humidity   wind     output(temp )(t+60)
 0              63        0          0         63
 60             63        0          2         104
```

Like this it should be run.

What I am trying to do is to display my output (next temperature value ) value in every 60 minutes. inputs will be added same as csv file . But output should be display in every 60 minutes.

I wrote the code for that. But It is not properly displaying my output.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

my code:

```
import datetime
data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv' , sep=',')
print(data)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
lastday = data.loc[0, 'date']
def convert_time(x):
  global lastday
  if x.date() == lastday.date():
    tm = x - lastday
    return tm.total_seconds()/60
else:
    lastday = x
    return 0

data['time'] = data['date'].apply(convert_time)
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)


data = data.values

X = 1
n_out = 1

x,y=list(),list()
start =0

for _ in range(len(data)):
  in_end = start+X
out_end= in_end + n_out
if out_end < len(data):
    x_input = data[start:in_end]
    x.append(x_input)

    while y.append(data[in_end:out_end,1]):
        if data['time'] <= 60:
            print(y)
            data['time']+=1
start +=1

 x = np.asanyarray(x)
 y = np.asanyarray(y)
```

my output:

```
[[ 63.][104.][ 93.][177.][133.][ 70.][ 83.][127.][205.][298.][234.][148.[135.][100.][166.]]
```

But here the issue came that

After 12:00:00 I measured the value at 13:45. So after 12:00:00 my output is displaying according to the 13:45 (mean 465 minute) value. But I want to get my output in every 60 min , if no value in that time I want to put it as 0 at that time.

What I want to write for output is

```
time         temp     humidity    wind
360          70        0           0
420          0         0           0
480          0         0           0
```

inputs should be added like this

```
 time        temp  humidity  wind
 0 min        63     0         0 
 0-60 min     63     0         2
    :
    :
```

Then here at

```
 12:00:00 ; 13:00:00
```

inputs :

```
 time (360:420 min )  70  0  0
 time (420:480 min)   83  0  0
```

This is the method that I am trying to do .But it didn't come nicely according to my code.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

csv file:
 [My csv file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KsAtm0vSsBfOL8z42UAPAwljaO1-DSKfdD9lSu3lv80/edit#gid=35707506)

Using resampling method, output:

[image]

Then the output:

Output after resampling:

[image]